# Backbone.js - Model URL vs Collection URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api

Ahoy everyone!

Good day! I'm starting to adapt the Backbone.js framework and I'm having a slippery grasp on how the Model's URL:

```
   var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
     urlRoot: 'http://localhost:3354/api/todo/GetAllTodo' // this guy right here
   }
```

affects the Collection's URL - once the said model is used in collection:

```
 var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: TodoItem,
                url: 'http://localhost:3354/api/todo/DosomethingElse' //Conflict of URL?
        }
```

Lastly, when I try the `model.fetch()`, the service returns a JSON representation of the data via `[{}]` format, this makes my model have an `object` property which houses the actual json data returned - this is a problem - as models are intended for a single record and not an `array[]` of data.

Thanks for your time and I really appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 4):

If you check Backbone source code for [`Model.url`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-65) , you'll see that the url base for a model is built by

```
var base = _.result(this, 'urlRoot') || _.result(this.collection, 'url');
```

which means your `TodoItem.urlRoot` takes precedences over `TodoList.url` when you do a `model.fetch()`

You can use [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) to extract the desired format:

```
var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'http://localhost:3354/api/todo/GetAllTodo',
    parse: function(data) {
        return data[0];
    }
}
```